# Jetpack Compose: Unable to set cursor to end of text in a TextField composable when first focused on it

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

Following the usual implementation, this is how we set the initial cursor to the end of text when setting the initial text:

```
var textState by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("Hello", TextRange(4))) }
TextField(
    value = textState,
    onValueChange = { textState = it }
)
```

However, it doesn't seem to work and the cursor appears at the beginning of the text when I first focus on it. What's wrong here?

If I do nothing in onValueChange (just for testing purpose), then it works where the cursor shows at the end. Somehow onValueChange is messing it up.

```
TextField(
    value = textState,
    onValueChange = {}
)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine to me.
There is an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/275157249) on the Google Issue Tracker that seems to go into the same direction, maybe it is related to your situation. A workaround proposed there is provided below, you can try if it works in your case:

```
var textState by rememberSaveable(stateSaver = TextFieldValue.Saver) {
    mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("Hello", TextRange(4)))
}
TextField(
    value = textState,
    onValueChange = { textState = it }
)
```

If this does not resolve the problem, please create a [new issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new) on the Issue Tracker. 
If it resolved the problem, give the existing problem a +1 and leave a comment there with your code sample to help them reproduce it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the issue reported is interesting, the solution didn't work for my case though, will create a new issue for it. Thanks!